# apply() function by row requires each row to be a numeric vector

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame such as in this example:

```
       sample1 sample2 sample3
test1  0.1     0.3     0.03
test2  0.24    0.4     0.5
...(many rows)
```

I am trying to `apply()` the function `sumlog()` from package `metap`, which calculates the combined p-value using Fisher's procedure, to each row of the data frame, each consisting of 3 p-values obtained in a given test ran in 3 independent samples.

This function works like this (for the p-values in the first row):

```
sumlog(c(0.1, 0.3, 0.03))
```

but since

```
dt[1,]
```

yields

```
              sample1 sample2 sample3
test1            0.6408721                 0.2650909              0.8808415
```

and

```
class(dt[1,])
```

is "data.frame", when I run the apply() function

```
apply(dt, 1, sumlog)
```

it returns

> Error in log(p[keep]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

which is the same that I obtain when running the `sumlog()` function for a single row:

> sumlog(dt[1,])
>       Error in log(p[keep]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

How could I make `apply()` take each row as a numeric vector for `sumlog()` to process it?

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(df, 6))
structure(list(sample1 = list(0.640872129337761, 
0.609000106674239, 0.895097234385105, 0.965620545232963, 
0.383226609468318, 0.577994668964293), sample2 = list(
0.265090939404131, 0.472455371057292, 0.0126943959203454, 
0.0968610413223728, 0.881022723350396, 0.311841106080399), 
sample3 = list(0.880841481464769, 0.924264965127336, 
    0.684971652341359, 0.07916491063753, 0.204131282086192, 
    0.259781528310932)), row.names = c("test1", "test2", 
"test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: sorry, I had forgot to change the names, I chose to name it dt and the row and column names this way for clarity

Comment: And now we see `df`? Yeah, you have some variable-name pollution going on ... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data has embedded lists ("list-columns").

```r
str(dt)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ sample1:List of 6
#   ..$ : num 0.641
#   ..$ : num 0.609
#   ..$ : num 0.895
#   ..$ : num 0.966
#   ..$ : num 0.383
#   ..$ : num 0.578
#  $ sample2:List of 6
#   ..$ : num 0.265
#   ..$ : num 0.472
#   ..$ : num 0.0127
#   ..$ : num 0.0969
#   ..$ : num 0.881
#   ..$ : num 0.312
#  $ sample3:List of 6
#   ..$ : num 0.881
#   ..$ : num 0.924
#   ..$ : num 0.685
#   ..$ : num 0.0792
#   ..$ : num 0.204
#   ..$ : num 0.26
```

While "normal" frames look like:

```r
str(mtcars[,1:3])
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

To do what you need, first you need to `unlist` each column, *then* you can do your stuff.

```r
dt[] <- lapply(dt, unlist)
apply(dt, 1, sum)
#    test1    test2    test3    test4    test5    test6 
# 1.786805 2.005720 1.592763 1.141646 1.468381 1.149617
```

(The use of `dt[] <-` instead of just `dt <-` is because `lapply` will return a `list` instead of a `data.frame`. By using `dt[]`, we're saying "overwrite the columns with this list of objects *but preserve `dt`'s class*".)

(I know I'm using `sum` and you're using `sumlog`, but I believe the premise is still correct and your needs will work with the non-`list` structure.)